# Customize Android app based on server values

Tags: java, android, firebase, server, remote-server

I want to developer an Android app such that a particular function should be executed in the app only when a value in the server is true. If the value in the server is false another function should be executed.

I know that It can be done using Firebase Remote Configuration but the problem is that the free package of Firebase has users limitation and also the caching of the values is done every 12 hours. I want to make it in such a way that any number of users should not be a problem and the values should not be cached and loaded from the server every time the retrieve function is called.

Is there any service that can do this for me? Or if not can it be done by myself?

Comment: Put the values in Realtime Database instead.

Comment: @DougStevenson I can do that but the number of users permitted in the free version may be an issue for me.

Comment: "using Firebase Remote Configuration but the problem is that the free package of Firebase has users limitation" As far as I know Remote Config does not have any limitation on the number of users. Can you be more concrete about the limit you experience/expect to experience?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen As far as I am aware is that Firebase spark plan has a limit of 100 device connecting to Firebase at a given time. I expect that more than 100 device would be connected to it on an given time.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please correct me if I am wrong with the info.

Comment: That limit applies to the Realtime Database, not to Remote Config.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the info. Can you also please help me with how to retrieve the current value every time I request for values rather than the cached values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42936878 ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Really Thank You for the link. Will test the Answer and then update you with the results.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Even after following the answer the cached values are being returned. Can you pls help. Should I Create a new Question for that?

Comment: It indeed sounds like a different question from what you originally posted. You might first want to comment on [@BobSnyder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42936878) to see if this approach still works for him. He's on Stack Overflow quite regularly, so that might be faster.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank You very much for your help. Tried a clean build and then the answer is working. Thank You once again. Can you please post a answer so that I can accept.

Comment: Hmm.... maybe there **is** a way to answer your original question. But if Bob's answer worked for you, your specific question on gettting non-cached values would be a duplicate of the one he answered.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen OK. Thank You very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit of 100 concurrent connections (for projects on the Spark/free plan) applies only to the Firebase Realtime Database. It does explicitly not apply to Firebase Remote Config, which is free and unlimited.